# Script for LockService not activating lock

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

With help from Tanaike, I have the following 'Add Row' Google Apps Script which triggers when a user clicks a button:

```
    //Add Row to Additional Duties Sheet
    function AddRowtoAdditionalDutiesSheet() {
      var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
      if (lock.tryLock(20000)) {
        try {

          var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
          spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getRange('3:3').getRow(), 1);
          spreadsheet.getRange('3:3').offset(0, 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
          spreadsheet.getRange('A4:X4').autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('A3:X4'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
          spreadsheet.getRange('3:3').clear({contentsOnly: true, commentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
          spreadsheet.getRange('F4:K4').autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('F3:K4'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
          spreadsheet.getRange('R4').autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('R3:R4'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
          spreadsheet.getRange('X4').autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('X3:X4'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
          spreadsheet.getRange('A3').activate();

        } catch(e) {
          throw new Error(e);
        } finally {
          lock.releaseLock();
        }
      }
    }
```

This is a copy of my sheet which has columns A to X.

[image]

The script copies formulas in certain cells from row 4 to row 3 after the row has been inserted. The script works most of the time but sometimes the formulas don't paste into row 3. It could be that there are a lot of users populating the sheet at the same time so the script doesn't get a chance to complete before another user activates the button. I can't work it out. The `LockService` was added to stop users activating the script again before the prior script had completed. I can't get the `LockService` to work so would appreciate some help with this. Otherwise, there may be another explanation as to why the pasting in the script doesn't work all of the time.

Comment: I have 2 questions for understanding your situation and 1 proposal. 1. Can I ask you about `The LockService was added to stop users activating the script again before the prior script had completed.`? In this case, an user run the script by clicking 2 times. Is my understanding correct? 2. When `20000` of `lock.tryLock(20000)` is increased, what result will you get? 3. As a workaround, when the user clicks the button, how about disabling the function of button? And when the script is finished, the function of button is enabled.

Comment: On a Monday morning, there could be up to 8 users populating the sheet at once so it is possible that they could hit the button at the same time. I have varied the lock from 5000 to 30000. The lock isn't activating. I clicked the ADD Row button activating the script 2 times within 5 seconds and 2 rows added. There is no lock

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I could replicate the situation of `The lock isn't activating.`, I would like to think of the solution. By the way, when the user clicks the button, how about disabling the function of button? By this, I thought that the duplicate click can be prevented.

Comment: I don't know how to disable the button after it's been clicked.

Comment: Thank you for replying. That can be achieved by a script. Now I'm trying to replicate your situation. But unfortunately, I still cannot do it. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. When I got it, I would like to post it as an answer.

Comment: About the disable of the button on Google Spreadsheet, in this case, this is not the direct solution. So although I cannot post this as an answer for your question, I prepared this on my repository. So you can see the sample script at my repository. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/28102d28b929e102f6fe88e7d42e2d64) About your main answer, I cannot still replicate your situation. I apologize for this. When I could do it, I would like to think of the solution.

Comment: I can't replicate the pasting error either but it seems to happen when pasting from F4 to F3 when it does happen

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation.